# Problema ao tentar fazer login com Vue, não é possível pegar a sessão em outras rotas no PHP

Tags: php, vue.js, session

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao tentar pegar um valor de um token guardado na sessão em outra rota. Tenho o método google no PHP onde é responsável por fazer o login com o google, gerar um token e guardar em uma sessão. O problema é que quando é redirecionado para a rota profile no front-end, ele verifica no método verifyToken no PHP se o token é igual ao token lá do localStorage, porém sempre retorna false já que o token não está sendo encontrado na rota, dá o seguinte aviso: Warning:  Undefined array key "token".

```
// arquivo login.vue

 async handleCredentialResponse(response) {

            try {
                const decodedResponse = jwt_decode(response.credential)

                const { data } = await callAxios.post('/auth/login/google', decodedResponse)

                console.log(data)

                authStore().setUser(JSON.stringify(data.user))
                authStore().setToken(data.token)

                this.$router.push({ name: 'profile' })
            }

            catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }

        },
```

```
 // Rota responsável por verificar se o token da sessão é igual ao token do localStorage

 public function verifyToken() {

        $tokenLocalStorage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'token', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $tokenSession = $_SESSION['token'];

        dd($tokenSession); // Aqui está o problema... ele me retorna null.
 
        if($tokenLocalStorage !== $tokenSession) {
            return jsonFormat(false);
        }

        return jsonFormat(true);
 }
```

```
 public function google() {

        // rota de login

        $userDatabase = new User;

        $token = generateToken(uniqid());
        $userGoogle = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $userFound = $userDatabase->findBy('google_user_id', $userGoogle->sub);
     
        if(!$this->check_email_verified($userGoogle)) {
            http_response_code(401);
        }   

        if(!$userFound) {
            return jsonFormat(false);
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
        }

        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

        return jsonFormat([
            "user" => [
                "name" => $userFound->name, 
                "photo" => $userFound->photo
            ],

            "token" => $token
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá, você tem que chamar a função `session_start()` antes de acessar os valores de sessão. Tente colocar a função depois da linha.

`$tokenLocalStorage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'token', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);`

Comment: Infelizmente não é isso, eu cheguei a testar e não foi. Fiquei testando e descobri que eu consigo pegar o valor da sessão quando não utilizo o vue para fazer o login, mas com ele não funciona, eu simplesmente não consigo ter acesso a uma sessão em outra rota. Por isso modifiquei a pergunta, talvez assim fique mais claro.